# Using authProvider with MS SDK for graph calls in C#

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying create a C# console application to connect to graph API and get a list of users from AzureAD from a tenant. I have registered the app and the admin has given me the following

- Tenant Name and Tenant ID
- Client ID (also sometimes called App Id)
- Client Secret

Using the sdk the C# code I need to use looks like this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

However, the console application will run as a batch process so there will be no user interaction at all. So in order to provide the authProvider I followed this article on MS docs site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS

And I think for my purpose I need to go for the "Client Credential OAuth flow". The code which is shown on that URL. But here it is too.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication clientApplication = ClientCredentialProvider.CreateClientApplication(clientId, clientCredential);
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientApplication);
```

The trouble is that Visual Studio does not recognise ClientCredentialProvider class. I'm not sure which assembly to import. I'm using the following usings in the top.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I'm not very experienced with GitHub repos and I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I would be interested in sample code; I have looked but cannot find any. MS have some lectures but they use another type of auth Provider which is authenticating interactively which is not what I'm looking for. I want obtain the token using the TenantId/ClientId and Client Secret.

Answer (score 55):

#### Update 2024-01-09:

The easiest way to authenticate with the Microsoft Graph SDK is to provide the *GraphServiceClient* a *TokenCredential* implementation from [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity) library, as described in [Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider based on the scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp).

The scenario described in this question calls for direct access to Microsoft Graph as the client (aka "app-only") using the client's credentials, so you'd use [*ClientSecretCredentials*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#using-a-client-secret) for authenticating with a secret, [*ClientCertificateCredentials*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#using-a-client-certificate) for authenticating with a certificate, [*ClientAssertionCredential*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientassertioncredential?view=azure-dotnet) for a federated identity credential, or [*ManagedIdentityCredential*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.managedidentitycredential?view=azure-dotnet) for authenticating as a managed identity.

For example, to use a client secret:

```cs
// The Microsoft Entra ID tenant ID or a verified domain (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com) 
var tenantId = "{tenant-id-or-domain-name}";

// The client ID of the app registered in Microsoft Entra ID
var clientId = "{client-id}";

// *Never* include client secrets in source code!
var clientSecret = await GetClientSecretFromKeyVault(); // Or some other secure place.

// Create an instance of a TokenCredential. Since we're using the Client Credentials
// flow with a client secret, we use ClientSecretCredential.
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

// The app registration should be configured to require access to permissions
// sufficient for the Microsoft Graph API calls the app will be making, and
// those permissions should be granted by a tenant administrator.
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Build the Microsoft Graph client
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

// Make a Microsoft Graph API request
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();
```

#### Original answer 2019-05-19:

*ClientCredentialProvider* is part of the Microsoft.Graph.Auth package. You can read more about this package at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth

Note that this package is currently (as of 2019-05-15) in preview, so you may want to wait before using this in a production application.

Alternatively, the following example uses the [Microsoft Authentication Library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) (MSAL) directly to set up the Microsoft Graph SDK using app-only authentication:

```
// The Azure AD tenant ID or a verified domain (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com) 
var tenantId = "{tenant-id-or-domain-name}";

// The client ID of the app registered in Azure AD
var clientId = "{client-id}";

// *Never* include client secrets in source code!
var clientSecret = await GetClientSecretFromKeyVault(); // Or some other secure place.

// The app registration should be configured to require access to permissions
// sufficient for the Microsoft Graph API calls the app will be making, and
// those permissions should be granted by a tenant administrator.
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/v2.0")
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

// Build the Microsoft Graph client. As the authentication provider, set an async lambda
// which uses the MSAL client to obtain an app-only access token to Microsoft Graph,
// and inserts this access token in the Authorization header of each API request. 
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
    new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {

            // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
            var authResult = await confidentialClient
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        })
    );

// Make a Microsoft Graph API query
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

(Note that this example uses the latest version of the Microsoft.Identity.Client package. Earlier versions (before version 3) did not include *ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder*.)

Comment: Thanks for the response Philippe. The code compiles fine but doesn't do much. I added a foreach after the last line to iterate through the users but it doesn't even go to the foreach line. I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: @gtrivedi We'll need some more concrete details in order to be able to help. Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through what's happening?

Comment: Yes I put a break point on the last line. var users... Immediately after that I have a foreach(var item in users){....} and the compiler exists and doesn't even go to the foreach loop.

Comment: I have same behavior: got token succesfully in DelegateAuthenticationProvider, but then infinity call of users request. But without MSAL library works for me. This works for example  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2 Maybe for some on it would be a solution, but I want to use library

Comment: After some fiddlering I have found a problem: graphClient.Me returns 404 (maybe permissions problem). So graphServiceClient.Users is working good. Is it possible to get error in code instead of fiddler?

Comment: Worth to mention that **Microsot.Graph.Auth** library is not going to leave prerelease stage at all. [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9137)

Comment: Hi @PhilippeSignoret. Do you happen to have any idea about this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69329470/why-is-my-graphserviceclient-reauthenticating-at-every-api-call

Comment: As of Microsoft.Graph.Beta 5.5.0-preview, this example no longer works as  *DelegateAuthenticationProvider* is not longer in the spec

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1368

Comment: @wruckie Thanks, I've added an update to demonstrate how to do this with the latest libraries.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above - at the time of writinf Sept 2021, the package: Microsoft.Graph.Auth is deprecated.  This means ClientCredentialProvider is no longer available.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/

The alternative is to use the solution propsed by [Philippe above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56154921/6155498).

Answer (score -3):

If you wanna cycle trough the users, replace the var users  with the following code:

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync().Result;
foreach (User user in users)
{
Console.WriteLine("Found user: " + user.Id);
}
```