# Why is my GraphServiceClient reauthenticating at every API call?

Tags: sdk, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using Microsoft Graph API to call some endpoints. I am using the SDK for C#.
When opening a fiddler trace, I found out that my _graphClientService is issuing an authentication to get a new token at every call. Why would that happen and how to prevent it?
[image]

It is also causing this error in some calls.

```
AADSTS50196: The server terminated an operation because it encountered a client request loop
```

Comment: What version of the Microsoft Graph SDK are you using? What  are you currently using to authenticate? Code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this piece of code works. It generates a GraphServiceClient that reuses the same token at every call, instead of generating a new one.

```
 public GraphServiceClient GenerateGraphUserClient()
    {
        string userToken = GetUserAccessToken();
        GraphServiceClient client= new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", userToken);
        }));
        return client;
    }

public string GetUserAccessToken()
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(_clientId)
        .WithTenantId(_domain)
        .Build();
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in _password)
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        var result = publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, _userName, securePassword).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MSAL.NET` you can cache a token. Public client applications (desktop/mobile apps) should try to get a token from the cache before acquiring a token by another method.

Acquisition methods on confidential client applications manage the cache themselves.

Resource:

[Token cache serialization in MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnetcore)

Comment: This did not help me. Indeed, It caches the token, but it does not return the GraphServiceClient that I use to call API endpoints. Instead, it returns the token in string and I need to use that token to build a HTTP Client and call the APIs with an HTTP Client, which is what I want to avoid. Any other lead?